# Moving array of values from one function to another in C

Tags: arrays, c, function

I'm working on a program that reads 5x5 matrix from .dat file, performs few tasks and saves outputs of those tasks to separate files. At the moment I've got two functions. One for reading from file and displaying values in console. And one for saving values in a file.

My problem is that those two work fine when I put them in main, but when I call them as functions only read_matrix() goes correct and write_matrix() just creates blank Result.dat. I figured it's because when they're all in main, after reading the matrix all values are in memory and can be written to the file. And when I call them as functions, write_matrix doesn't have any values in A[] and gives me nothing. I've tried creating another array to hold those values, messing with pointers (I'm not very familiar with them), but nothing worked and I'm out of ideas.

1. How do I fix it? How do I pass entire array of values from first function to the other one?
2. How could I make program determine dimensions. Matrix I have to work with is 5x5, but I'd like to be able to use this program with other sizes. Currently I prompt user to input height and width, but it's far from perfect, if I input incorrect dimensions output is wrong.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>


int read_matrix(FILE * fin, int ** A, int x, int y) {
  fin = fopen("mat_A.dat", "r");
  if (fin == NULL)
    printf("Error opening input file.  \n");

  else {
    printf("Number of columns:\n");
    scanf("%d", & x);
    printf("Number of rows:\n");
    scanf("%d", & y);
    // Read the matrix dimensions
    int ** A = (int ** ) malloc(sizeof(int * ) * x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        A[i] = (int * ) malloc(sizeof(int) * y);
      }
    }

    // Allocate the memory
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
        fscanf(fin, "%d", & A[i][j]);
        printf("%d   ", A[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fin);
  }
}

int write_matrix(FILE * fout, int ** A, int x, int y) {
  fout = fopen("Result.dat", "w");
  // fprintf( fout, "%d %d \n", x, y );

  for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
      fprintf(fout, "%d ", A[i][j]);
    }
    fprintf(fout, "\n");
  }
  fclose(fout);
}

int main() {
  /*  declaration of variables  */
  int x,
      y,
      i = 0, 
      **A;
      FILE * fin,
           * fout;

  read_matrix(fin, A, x, y);

  write_matrix(fout, A, x, y);

  printf("\n\nlul");
  free(A);
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: The pointer `A` in `read_matrix` is a local copy. Changing `A` in `read_matrix` has no effect on the pointer `A` in `main`. You either need to pass the address of `A` to `read_matrix`, or return the new value of `A` from `read_matrix` and assign it to `A` in `main`.

Comment: you should use `&A` or return a `int **` from read_matrix

Comment: `int ** A = (int ** ) malloc(sizeof(int * ) * x);` hides the `read_matrix` function's second parameter `int **A`.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @user3386109. You set me on the right track and I found a solution. I don't know how to give you dem reputation points, but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that returns Result.txt with values inside. In my original code not only I wasn't giving `write_matrix()` any values, but I also wasn't giving it any dimensions.
Here's what I did to get my text file with matrix inside.

1. In 1st function I added return A; at the end.
2. I moved asking user for dimensions from 1st function to main. That way they're not lost after 1st function ends.
3. In main I created another int **B pointer.
4. I used that pointer when calling 1st function and then used it as an argument when calling second function.

Here's how `write_matrix()` and `main()` look after changes.

```
int **read_matrix(int x, int y)
{
    int ** A = NULL;
    FILE * fin = fopen("mat_A.dat", "r");

    ...

        fclose(fin);
    }
    return A;
}

void write_matrix (int **B, int x, int y)
{
    FILE *fout = fopen( "Result.txt", "w" );

    for( int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < y; j++ )
        {
            fprintf( fout, "%d ", B[ i ][ j ] );
        }
        fprintf( fout, "\n" );
    }
    fclose( fout );
}

int main(void)
{
    /*  deklaracja i inicjalizacja zmiennych  */
    int x, y;
    int **B;

    printf("Number of columns:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x );
    printf("Number of rows:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y );
    printf("\n");

    B = read_matrix (x, y);

    if (B != NULL)
        write_matrix (B, x, y);

    printf("\n\nlul");
    free(B);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a good step forward. Well done. However, there is a flaw. The variable `A` in `main` is not initialized. The `read_matrix` function doesn't change that. So the line `free(A)` is not valid. If you're lucky `A` will be 0, and `free(A)` will do nothing. If you're unlucky, the line `free(A)` will cause the program to crash.

Comment: The easiest way for me to show how to fix the issue is by editing the answer. You can view the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65831527/revisions) to see the changes. In summary, the `read_matrix` function doesn't need `A` as a parameter. It can simply declare `A` as a local variable. And `main` doesn't need `A` at all. The same is true for `fin` and `fout`.